# Store Reminder in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am trying to store a [Reminder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in the IsolatedStorage. It works at runtime but if I restart the app all data is gone.

Here some code to make fun about:

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

private List<ScheduledAction> getStorage()
{
    if (!userSettings.Contains("notifications"))
    {
        userSettings.Add("notifications", new List<ScheduledAction>());
    }

    return (List<ScheduledAction>)userSettings["notifications"];
}
private void saveStorage(List<ScheduledAction> list)
{
    userSettings["notifications"] = list;
}

private void test()
{
    List<ScheduledAction> list = getStorage();
    Reminder alarm = new Reminder("name");
    list.Add(alarm);
    saveStorage(list);
}
```

My current guess why the object is not stored is that `Reminder` is not serializable. Since this is not my object what can I do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we add or update in [IsolatedStorageSettings.Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)  , need to save before application exit.   I made little changes in your code, may this will  help you.

```
private List<ScheduledAction> getStorage()
{
    if (!userSettings.Contains("notifications"))
    {
        userSettings.Add("notifications", new List<ScheduledAction>());
       userSettings.Save();
    }

    return (List<ScheduledAction>)userSettings["notifications"];
}

private void saveStorage(List<ScheduledAction> list)
{
    userSettings["notifications"] = list;
    userSettings.Save();
}
```

Comment: ah yes, I created `saveStorage` to do the `Save()` here and forgot :) now I get `System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException`. I guess Reminder is not serializable.